# Replace a specific (not all the matches) regex match on java or kotlin

Tags: java, android, regex, kotlin

I have different regex in a regex substitution system, for example

```
"([e][u][r])+" = "euros"
"([e][u][r][o][s])+" = "currency"
```

But I want to replace:

```
 1. The longest match for all the regex occurrences if more than 2 regex are true for the same part of text
 2. Just apply one time a rule for a part of text
```

If I have a text similar to this (text is not splitted by lines)

```
150,00 euros
42,00 eur
12,00 eureureuros
```

I have this ocurrences:

**First line two occurrences**

```
eur = euros (first line, match 3 characters)
euros = currency (first line, match 5 characters)
```

We choose the longest one (euros = currency)

**Second line, one occurrence**

```
eur = euros (second line, match 3 characters)
```

**Third line, two occurrences**

```
eur = euros (match 9 characters)
euros = currency (match 5 characters)
```

The result must be

```
150,00 currency (because euros = currency is the longest match)
42,00 euros (because we apply eur = euros but after that we DON'T apply euros = currency because we just apply one replacement for a part of text)
12,00 eurosos
```

Is there any way to replicate this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What exactly should be the result for '12,00 eureureuros'. Is it '12,00 eurosos'? And what about '12,00 euroseuroseuroseur'?

Comment: Hi paul, that's because we need to replace the largest rule in case of two or more rules coincident with some portion of the text

eur rule is longer match than "euros" rule.

The result will be eurosos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way I would solve it: [jdoodle.com/a/23Xw](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/23Xw)

```
public class MyClass {
   static List<Replacement> _regexes = new ArrayList<Replacement>();

   private static String parseWord(String word) {
        // Variables for holding the best match.
        String longest = "";
        String replacement = "";

        // Check all possible replacements.
        for (Replacement regex: _regexes) {
            // Find the longest possible match.
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(" + regex.Source + ")+");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(word);

            // Check all matches and store it if one is longer that the current one.
            while(m.find()) {
                String match = m.group();
                if (match.length() > longest.length()) {
                    longest = match;
                    replacement = regex.Target;
                }
            }
        }

        // Finally apply the replacement.
        String result = word.replace(longest, replacement);

        return result;
    }

    private static String parse(String text) {
        // Split text into words.
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList(text.split(" "));
        // Apply replacements.
        words = words.stream().map(word -> parseWord(word)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        // Join the words again to a text.
        return String.join(" ", words);
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
      _regexes.add(new Replacement("euros", "currency"));
      _regexes.add(new Replacement("eur", "euros"));
      Collections.sort(_regexes);

      List<String> data = Arrays.asList("150,00 euros", "42,00 eur", "12,00 eureureuros", "15,00 euroseuroseuroseur euros eur");
      for (String text: data) {
          String result = parse(text);
          System.out.println(text + " - " + result);
      }
    }
}

public class Replacement implements Comparable<Replacement> {
  public String Source;
  public String Target;

  public Replacement(String source, String target) {
      this.Source = source;
      this.Target = target;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Replacement r) {
    return r.Source.length();
  }  
}
```

Comment: This implementation is quite good, but it is still not working properly, if the text is not split by lines, for example       

List<String> data = Arrays.asList("150,00 euros 42,00 eur 12,00 eureureuros 15,00 euroseuroseuroseur");

Comment: What should happen in that case? You were talking about "only the longest match should be replaced", which would be "euroseuroseuroseur". This is exactly what the code does. If you want it differently you need to think about how to split your text in proper parts.

Comment: Then, you think that there is no possible implementation if I do not split the text into lines? Maybe you are right I have to think it ...

The problem is that "only the longest match should be replaced in case of ambiguity for the same part of the text, but if we match two separate regex for two separate part of the text, we must replace both for example "12,00 euros eur" will result "12,00 currency euros"

Comment: There is an implementation for almost everything as long as the rules are defined properly. ;) I changed the implementation and the replacement is now done per word.

Answer (score 2):

This answers the original question.
You can use the function `replace()` twice.
The order of the replacements is important.
First replace the longest which is `"euros"` with `"currency"` and then replace `"eur"` with `"euros"`.
Only 1 of the replacements will actually work in your case.
For `"150,00 euros"`:

```
val s1 = "150,00 euros"
val new1 = s1.replace("euros", "currency").replace("eur", "euros")
println(new1)
```

Result:

```
150,00 currency
```

For `"42,00 eur"`:

```
val s2 = "42,00 eur"
val new2 = s2.replace("euros", "currency").replace("eur", "euros")
println(new2)
```

Result:

```
42,00 euros
```

Comment: We cannot separate the lines, we have to process all the text as a unit.

Then, it is more difficult, because we have to apply one or other rules depending of the match size ...

Thanks !!!

Comment: In my answer I have 2 examples, 1 for each case. I do not separate the lines. If `s` contains your string then `s.replace("euros", "currency").replace("eur", "euros")` will work in any case.

Comment: For example, in an orientation like this:

12,00 eureureuros, with the replace system we will obtain

12,00 eureureur[currency], because we obtain euros = currency, but we have a longest match with the eur = euros rule -> [eureureureur]os

Comment: Your question does not mention any of these cases that you posted in your comment.

Comment: So what you did is invalidate this answer and the answer is already downvoted.

Comment: I edit the question with another example in order to explain the problem better. Thanks for your answer !!!!